# How do you use reflection to get a sub property?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Let's see if I can explain what I'm trying to do...

Say I have an object, with a path to a property that looks like this:

**Appointment.Person.Name**

If I want to update the "Person" property, i could do something like this:

```
PropertyInfo subPropertyInfo = apptObject.GetType().GetProperty("Person");
subPropertyInfo.SetValue(apptObject, replacementValue, null);
```

But how would I update the Name Property for the root object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get hold of the current value of `Person`, then update it in the same way as you currently are:

```
PropertyInfo subPropertyInfo = apptObject.GetType().GetProperty("Person");
Object p = subPropertyInfo.GetValue(apptObject);

PropertyInfo subSubPropertyInfo = p.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
subSubPropertyInfo.SetValue(p, replacementValue, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
PropertyInfo subPropertyInfo = apptObject.Person.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
subPropertyInfo.SetValue(apptObject.Person, replacementValue, null);
```